# Cannot boot Ubuntu Gnome 16.10

Tags: live-usb

I have a live USB of Ubuntu Gnome 16.10 created with Rufus. The same live USB works on other computers without a hitch. It is USB 3.0, plugged into an Asrock H110m ITX-ac motherboard. I am using an Nvidia GPU, but regardless of whether or not I use nomodeset as a parameter, it returns the same error:

```
[5.777228] scsi host5: runtime PM trying to activate child device host5 but parent(1-6:1.0) is not active
[5.408116] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[5.408145] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[7.035903] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[7.035919] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[7.460303] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Unsupported splx structure
```

The USB was created using Rufus in GPT mode, I booted the UEFI partition for the live USB. It already has Windows 10 installed on the PC. How can I get it to successfully boot?

Comment: Please kindly paste all the __outputted error message__ leaving some thing out means you limit the chances of getting a good help.

Comment: Possibly a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1629714

Comment: @George I added the rest of the error message as you suggested

Comment: @CelticWarrior it looks like it is the same bug, are there any fixes for it?